# Caching intermediate dataframes to test spark performance

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark

I need to measure the performance of my PySpark code. To eliminate influence from pre-processing steps which should not factor into the running time, I cache my intermediate dataframes. That is,

```
for i in iiis:
    df_cache = ini_df.sample(False, 1/len(iiis))
    df_cache.cache.count()
```

However, I run out of memory everytime I try to do this because the original dataframe was too big. Any idea how I can measure the run time of my code without using the `cache` function?

Comment: Its a bit unclear which piece of code are you measuring performance here. I guess your requirement here is to avoid lazy computation and  break the lineage of dataframe so you can measure performance of individual operations. In that case I suggest you persist to disk.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to avoid lazy computation here. My problem is that I don't have enough memory to store the cached data, but my spark job has to have a low RAM requirement and be sufficiently fast at the same time.

Comment: In that case you have to avoid caching to memory and as I suggested try persisting it to disk, that would break the lineage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataframe is too big for memory, you should try to `persist` it on disk.

```
from pyspark import StorageLevel
df_cache.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

On my environment, persist on disk only or on memory only result the same performances.

Comment: It would be strange, if it is almost the same, but maybe on smaller df. On big one (fist to RAM) it should be significantly different, even with SSD disks.